# Vuejs : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "addEventListener", dateOfEntrance is null

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a form with a two dates (Entry and Exit). I would like to compare the two dates and make sure that the release date is before the exit date.
Unfortunately, I get a `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "addEventListener", dateOfEntrance is null` error.
This is my javascript code (`Vuejs 3 Api composition`)

```
<script>
// Dates Management
const dateOfEntrance = document.getElementById("date_of_entrance");
const dateOfRelease = document.getElementById("date_of_release");
const dateError = document.getElementById("date-error");

const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

const compare = () => {
  const startDate = new Date(dateOfEntrance.value).getTime();
  const endDate = new Date(dateOfRelease.value).getTime();

  if (endDate < startDate) {
    dateError.classList.remove("hidden");
    submitButton.disabled = true;
  } else {
    dateError.classList.add("hidden");
    submitButton.disabled = false;
  }
};

dateOfEntrance.addEventListener("change", compare);
dateOfRelease.addEventListener("change", compare);

</script>
```

and the html code

```
          <CardBox>
            <FormField label="Entry date & Release date">
              <FormControl
                id="date_of_entrance"
                v-model="form.date_of_entrance"
                name="date_of_entrance"
                :icon="mdiCalendarPlus"
                type="date"
                placeholder="Date of entrance"
                required
              />
              <FormControl
                id="date_of_release"
                v-model="form.date_of_release"
                name="date_of_release"
                :icon="mdiCalendarPlus"
                type="date"
                placeholder="Date of release"
                required
              />
            </FormField>

            <div
              id="date-error"
              class="hidden italic mt-2 text-red-800 text-xs"
            >
              <p>The release date must be before the entry date.</p>
            </div>
            </template>
          </CardBox>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid mixing Vue-style with raw JS style, in this case accessing DOM elements or adding event listeners directly. Let Vue handle it for you.

Instead, just create a computed property which will indicate if there is an error with the dates:

```
const startDateIsBeforeEndDate = computed(() => {
  const startDate = new Date(form.date_of_entrance).getTime();
  const endDate = new Date(form.date_of_release).getTime();
  return startDate <= endDate 
})
```

(I assume `form` is reactive, not a ref, otherwise it has to be `form.value.date_of_entrance`)

In your template:

```html
<div
  v-if="!startDateIsBeforeEndDate"
  class="italic mt-2 text-red-800 text-xs"
>
  <p>The release date must be before the entry date.</p>
</div>
```

Now the computed property will be updated when the `form.date_of_entrance` or `form.date_of_release` data changes, and the error message will be shown according to the computed property.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution,
When I use your code I get the errors `ReferenceError: dateOfEntrance/dateOfRelease is not defined`.
I added the code
`const dateOfEntrance = document.getElementById("date_of_entrance");
const dateOfRelease = document.getElementById("date_of_release");`,
I get an error `TypeError: can't access property "value", dateOfEntrance is null`, `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "value", dateOfEntrance is null`.
isn't there an example or a vuejs tutorial that I can refer to?

Comment: Ah, got me confused with the `.value`, I though those were refs, but they were your input elements. You have to use the data you put into the inputs, check the updated answer (I assume the `form` is a reactive Proxy, not a ref)